# Specifics about shifting floating point data types in .Net?

Tags: .net, bit-shift

If I remember right, a double or float is broken into 3 parts: a sign bit, the exponent, and the mantissa.

When a double is shifted, do the bits shift the entire binary of the variable or does it just shift the mantissa?

Comment: The `double` type cannot be bit-shifted in .NET (the `shl` instruction only works for integer types)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't shift floating point types - in C# at least.

On the other hand, if you were to multiply or divide by two repeatedly, you'd see what I mentioned before: within the range of normalized numbers, shifting left would increase the exponent by one and shifting right would decrease the exponent by one. Within denormal numbers, the exponent is fixed at 0, so the mantissa has to change.

EDIT: To answer your comment, a value represents a subnormal/denormal number if the exponent is zero and the mantissa is non-zero. See [this page](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) for more information on IEEE 754 in general, and I have a page on [.NET binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx).

Comment: Do you have a link for the difference between normalized and denormal floating points? Given a double that's been pulled out of a database or a file, how can you tell if it's normalized or not?

Comment: Given that your previous answer may not have applied in .Net... You still peeked my interested about normalized and denormalized numbers, where can I read up on those even if they're not .Net specific?

Comment: @Corey: I've expanded my contracted answer, including a couple of links.

Comment: Picked for answer (and +1) because of extra information including how I would just shift the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, shift operators are only defined on Integers in .Net.